# bot.sendphoto does not work asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webclient, telegram-bot

I have a problem when I use the following code:

```
try
{
    var url = "https://www.telegadmin.com/image/tinakish/qavasi.jpg";
    var uri = new Uri(url);

    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(uri))
        {
            //bot.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, "تا اینجا اوکیه", replyMarkup: mainMenu);
             bot.SendPhotoAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, new FileToSend("test.jpg", stream), caption: "این تصویر از سرور برای شما ارسال شده است", replyMarkup: mainMenu);

            return Ok();
        }


    }
    return Ok();

}
catch(Exception ex){
    bot.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id,ex.ToString(), replyMarkup: mainMenu);
    return Ok();

}
```

It's working for me in C#, but does not work in setwebhook. Can you help me?

Comment: catch error wont appear for me,how can debug this at server?

Comment: just wondering, should not be full path to "test.jpg" ?

Comment: no,test.jpg is not my  file!!!!,this is name for saving on telegram server,my file has a  url full path, and I put this into stream but does not work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Bot.SendPhotoAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, new FileToSend("test.jpeg", stream), caption: "این تصویر از سرور برای شما ارسال شده است", replyMarkup: mainMenu).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

you didn't execute the task.

Comment: you are welcome. please consider marking the question as a answer in order to close the topic. thanks